# Ok to ask for alpha and beta testers?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[Omnichess](https://www.facebook.com/Omniwidget/?ref=aymt_homepage_panel) is an application I am planning on developing until release.

I'd like to find volunteer alpha and beta testers for it, and was wondering if it was appropriate to ask for them on the arqade stack?

Comment: On the main site, that would likely be off-topic. If it's appropriate anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, it would probably be in chat (the main Arqade room is called 'The Bridge'). I'd just caution against immediately posting links in case anyone has an itchy spam trigger finger; but feel free to chat with us, explain you are developing a game and ask is anyone is interested in alpha/beta testing (chat *tends* to be more active during the North American daytime)

Comment: @Trent Hawkins thanks

Comment: More to what @TrentHawkins said: NA time on **weekdays** is a good time to ask. [A good visulation of active times can be found here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking for beta testers on the arqade stack is off topic; Your post would likely be closed for advertising / spam.